# Change wordpress header image randomly after a set amount of time

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a header image on my WordPress page that loads 6 images randomly when you enter my site. I'm trying to switch that group of images when a user is on my site. I'm using this code but something is wrong if I use the `<?php echo $header; ?>`:

```
function show_banner(){
    document.getElementById('masthead').style.backgroundImage="url('<?php echo $header; ?>')";
}

window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout(show_banner, 2000);
};
```

If I set the url to a real link, it works, but I need it to load a randomly image from the ones that are already uploaded. This are my variables:

```
<?php
      do_action('lithestore_start_header');
      $header=get_header_image();
      $header_class='';
      $header_picture='';
      if(is_home() || is_front_page()){
        if(has_header_image()){
          $header_class=" site-cover";
          $header_picture=' style="background-image:url('.esc_url($header).');"';
        }
      }
    ?>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header<?php echo esc_html($header_class);?>" role="banner"<?php echo $header_picture;?>>

        <?php
        /**
         * Hook lithestore_header
         * @hooked lithestore_before_navigation - 0
         * @hooked lithestore_custom_logo - 10
         * @hooked lithestore_primary_navigation - 20
         * @hooked lithestore_top_buttons - 30
         * @hooked lithestore_after_navigation - 40
         * @hooked lithestore_cover - 50
         */
        do_action('lithestore_header');
        ?>
    </header>
```

Also, how can I assign a loop to the script so it doesn't change the image just one time?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your php executes on the server so you can't do anything like <?php echo $header; ?> in your javascript. Check out this function for telling your javascript about values you have in php https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Your php code starts off with

$header=get_header_image();
But the code you pasted hasn't defined the "get_header_image();" function.

I imagine that you will need to show us the "get_header_image();" code in order for us to determine what is wrong with this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code starts off with

```
$header=get_header_image();
```

But the code you pasted hasn't defined the "get_header_image();" function.

I imagine that you will need to show us the "get_header_image();" code in order for us to determine what is wrong with this function.

Comment: I believe `get_header_image()` is a built in [wordpress function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header_image).